# Java CircleArea what is wrong?

Tags: java

What is wrong with my code?

After running, it asks about radius value and then nothing more happens?
I could search it on google but I just want to know what is wrong with exactly  this code :)

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CircleArea {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter radius value ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        input.nextLine();
        String radius;
        radius = input.nextLine();
        double r;
        r = Double.parseDouble(radius);
        double circleArea;
        circleArea = r * Math.PI * r;
        System.out.println("CircleArea :" + circleArea);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `nextLine` statements, remove the first

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// This is waiting for input, but the value is ignored
//input.nextLine();

// This is waiting for input and stores the result
String radius;
radius = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling input.nextLine() without assigning the value to it and then waiting for second input. Also instead of getting next line use nextDouble() this way you will save casting and directly getting a double variable.

Example:
    Remove the line:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
input.nextLine(); // This one here
```

Change the way you get the double from the input:

```
double radius = input.nextDouble();
```